# What is the mark-up language used for designing interfaces / applications in mobile?

Tags: ios, mobile, mobile-development

For web apps / interfaces, we use HTML5. What is the equivalent of this in the mobile environment?

I'm looking at Sketch as a WYSIWYG solution to designing mobile interfaces but what is the underlying mark-up / technology behind it?

Comment: iOS Interface Builder creates XML files, but this is undocumented as far as I am aware.  Some tools generate Swift or Objective C code to create the UI that has been designed with the tool

Answer (score 1):

We can use various options depending on the platform and requirements.

1. Sometimes I use **Altova MobileTogether** which uses visual
   programming to design the user interface and functional programming
   using the standardized XQuery/XPath. It can be used to develop Android,
   iOS, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8, and HTML5 Browser Based Client apps.
2. **Appception**, which uses HTML, CSS, and JavaScript; can be used to
   develop for Android and iOS.
3. **Appear IQ**: Mobile Web Apps (HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript) or Native Apps
   (Java, Objective-C, C#.NET/VB.NET for Windows Phone); can be used to
   develop for Android, iOS, Windows/Windows Phone.
4. **Appery.io**: HTML, JavaScript, CSS, jQueryMobile, PhoneGap; can be used to
   develop for Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Mobile web.
5. **Convertigo Mobilizer MEAP**: HTML, CSS, JavaScript; can be used to develop
   for Android, BlackBerry, iPhone, Windows Mobile.
6. **Corona** uses Lua; can be used to develop for iOS, Android,
   and NOOK Color.
7. **IBM MobileFirst Studio**: HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, and Native SDK Languages
   with Native Worklight API; can be used to develop for iOS, BlackBerry 6,7, &
   10, Android, Windows Phone 7.5 & 8, Windows 8 Desktop and Tablets,
   Adobe AIR, Mobile Web App, Desktop Browser Web Page.
8. **iOS**: uses Objective-C and Swift; can be used to develop for iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch